# Python conditions incorrect

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
keyword = 'SUCCESS'
newList = []
for item in stockList:
    for lul in item:
        if lul[-1] == keyword and lul[0] not in newList:
            newList.append(lul[0])
            print(message)
print(newList)
time.sleep(3)
```

So I want to constantly check an excel sheet waiting for updates, however if I already have one of the lists in my 'newList' I don't want to print out that old row since it was already recorded. However this isn't working and this is the output

```
DAL reached the alert price down
FB reached the alert price down
GOOGL reached the alert price down
GPS reached the alert price up
GRUB reached the alert price down
LUV reached the alert price down
MSFT reached the alert price down
MU reached the alert price up
PFE reached the alert price down
PPH reached the alert price down
QQQ reached the alert price down
T reached the alert price down
TSLA reached the alert price down
VNQ reached the alert price up
VTI reached the alert price down
['BA', 'DAL', 'FB', 'GOOGL', 'GPS', 'GRUB', 'LUV', 'MSFT', 'MU', 'PFE', 'PPH', 'QQQ', 'T', 'TSLA', 'VNQ', 'VTI']
```

This just runs in a loop, when ideally the second run should be empty because all of the indicators lul[0] is already in my newList so it should ignore printing that. If that makes sense

Comment: You set `newList` to the empty list before the loop runs.

Comment: can't believe I didn't realize that, thank you so much!